# Cannot call $class_name::hello() but Artist::hello() work

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have two files in same directory:

**`Artist.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace Bcdcnt\Models;

class Artist {
    public static function hello() {
        echo "hello!";
    }
}
```

**`index.php`**:

```
<?php

include 'Artist.php';

use Bcdcnt\Models\Artist;

$class_name = "Artist";
$class_name::hello();
```

When run index.php, this shows error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Artist' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\index.php on line 8`

**but if I replace $class_name in index.php by "Artist", it works.**

```
<?php

include 'Artist.php';

use Bcdcnt\Models\Artist;

Artist::hello();
```

I don't know why can not use class name as a variable?

Comment: It's not the same, Mike. If i'm not using namespace, $class_name::hello() worked too.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
call_user_func($class_name . "::hello");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: I tried and not work, too. It says: "Class Artist not found in..."

Comment: Try with the full namespace along with the class name, or call_user_func(array($class_name, "hello"));

Comment: It also does not work. It says: "Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Artist' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\index.php on line 9"

Comment: Anyway, call_user_func(array('Bcdcnt\Models\\' . $class_name, 'hello')); worked! It must contained namespace.